# Jmeter testing for localhost server?

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests

I want to use Jmeter as performance testing tool for my java web project but my project is on localhost server which is Tomcat server. How can i able to do performance testing of my project using Jmeter?

Comment: Please let me know if any details are required?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65430096/4307338

Answer (score 0):

You can do that...just provide the IP address for the request and If it hits the server then you will get the response.

Below is more info from @Dmitri T post:-

Meter doesn't care whether application under test is local or remote, if you cannot hit local URL with JMeter - something is wrong with your HTTP Request Sampler configuration, most likely "Port" value is wrong.

In order to be able to help we need to know the following: 1. URL of your application 2. Output of View Results Tree listener 3. Contents of JMeter log 4. Description of screenshot of your HTTP Request sampler

As an alternative option you can try recording your scenario using JMeter Chrome Extension and see if you're able to replay recorded scenario without errors. Again, use View Results Tree listener to inspect request and response details.

In general it is not recommended to run the application under test and the load generator on the same physical or virtual machine as the load generator (JMeter in your case) may consume immense amount of resources like CPU and RAM and it may interfere your application health (unless you're using completely isolated containers), so I would recommend use separate hosts for application and the load generator.

Reference:-[How to make Jmeter recognize "localhost" URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666220/how-to-make-jmeter-recognize-localhost-url)

Comment: Thanks for sharing great knowledge.